# Caching an action in a multi-language website using Play Framework's Cached API

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3, playframework-2.4

In order to cache actions per label and language for a given number of seconds, I wrote the following helper method (where label, is the name I give to my action):

```
def cacheResponseFor(label: String, duration: Int)(action: EssentialAction) = { 
   Cached({r: RequestHeader => (label + getLanguage(r))}, duration){ action }
}

def getLanguage(request: RequestHeader): String = {
   request.cookies
     .get(helpers.SessionHelpers.LANGUAGE_SESSION)
        .map(_.value)
          .getOrElse(helpers.LanguageHelpers.FRENCH)
}
```

But I'm experiencing something weird, when I try to cache an `Action` for 60s and switch languages in the meantime to English from French for example, I keep getting the French version for 60s then it switches to english.

After investigating, I found that method `getLanguage` **is not called at each call to that action** as if the Key gets evaluated only after the caching period ends.

This is not right, I would want this `cacheResponseFor` to be called everytime I request my page, the language gets evaluated using `getLanguage` and I get the right cached version, i.e. I should end up with 2 cached actions (one per language).

Am I missing something?

Comment: looks really weird it may even be a play bug, did you check where the cached version comes from? Is it cached at client(server will return NotModified) or cached in server side?

Comment: It is supposed to be cached on server side, server returns 200 Ok

Comment: Could it be that your LANGUAGE_SESSION is not yet changed for the new request, thus hitting the cache with the previous one set? the getOrElse will not be triggered if you have LANGUAGE_SESSION already set.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is in the `getLanguage` method. Try this, as recommended by the [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaI18N#Retrieving-supported-language-from-an-HTTP-request):

```
def getLanguage(request: RequestHeader): String = {
    request.acceptLanguages
           .map(_.code)
           .headOption
           .getOrElse(helpers.LanguageHelpers.FRENCH)
}
```

Also, take a look at [`Controller.request2lang()`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Controller@request2lang(implicitrequest:play.api.mvc.RequestHeader):play.api.i18n.Lang) method and see if it could be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what is the issue you are facing but I did a small proof of concept and there is no issue at all.

```
package controllers

import play.api.cache.Cached
import play.api.mvc.{Action, Controller, EssentialAction, RequestHeader}

object Caches {
  import play.api.Play.current

  def cacheResponseFor(label: String, duration: Int)(action: EssentialAction) = {
    Cached({r: RequestHeader => label + getLanguage(r)}, duration){ action }
  }

  def getLanguage(request: RequestHeader): String = {
    request.cookies
      .get("language")
      .map(_.value)
      .getOrElse("fr")
  }
}

class CachedApplication () extends Controller {

  import Caches._

  def index = cacheResponseFor("homePage", 60) {
    Action { implicit req =>
      getLanguage(req) match {
        case "fr" =>
          Ok("Bonjour le monde")
        case _ =>
          Ok("Hello world")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you switch languages during the 60 seconds period?

Comment: Yes, changing the cookie and reloading the page

Comment: I even debugged it and saw getLanguage being called two times for a non cached request and one for a cached request.

Comment: Weird, will try to check this out on the weekend, will let you know.