# Cache Following language PlayFramework 2 and ehcache

Tags: performance, caching, ehcache, playframework-2.3

I have a Play Framework 2 application with intertionalization.

I use the CacheApi embedded in Play (ehCache) with standard configuration.
I made an example with index page:

```
@Inject @NamedCache("session-cache") CacheApi cache;
```

then

```
@Cached(key = "index")
public Result index() {
    //Controller.changeLang("fr");

    return ok(index.render(this.userProvider,"c-layout-header-fullscreen",NEWS_FORM));
}
```

When i launch first page and refresh it seems to work but i have a method to change the lang (or detect automatically the browser lang/country)

```
public Result changeLanguage(String code) {
    Controller.changeLang(Language.findByCode(code).code);
    return redirect(controllers.routes.Application.index().toString());
}
```

when i change the language the same page as before cached in first language page ordered is displayed.

1. How i can specify the cache for a language (if i have 3 languages, 3 differents index page cached). Same problem for DB translation i want to chache result query but following the language it will be different. I want to cache the translation query because it will use DB lot of.
2. what is difference between session-cache, db-cache, user-cache ?

Comment: Hi, I think you need to handle the cache inside the  method index() using the language as a part of the key.

Comment: maybe but all page are retrieved automatically with annotation and with @Cached, i don't know how to achieve it to restitute the result from cache with annotation it is automatic

Comment: The content is different for different languages so is normal that you can't use the same key.

Comment: marci i know that but maybe there is something existing to make it work, i mean it is a common process to have internationalized content.. and cache ?

Comment: I think you have to do something custom (like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319654/caching-an-action-in-a-multi-language-website-using-play-frameworks-cached-api). Maybe you can try to pass the language as a parameter of the controller and test if the cache helper handle it differently.

Comment: thank you /java /scala little different, and i don't understant what they 're doing, moreover it is a poc (not tested) thanks !